# Flash AS3 Do nothing until loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, text, load

I have this program, that needs to load a text file, which it can do, but since everything is multi-threaded on AS3, it continues with the program even though its not loaded. Like, if I was to make a function that loads the text, and then have it return the loaded text, it will always return "undefined". I have to add an event listener for when it's done, but the way I have to handle the returning of the text is awkward. Is there any way to make the program just wait, or do nothing until it's loaded?

Comment: Show please a bit of your code, it is not clear what you have tried till now. It would be great if you would share the whole source which shows the issue.

Comment: It's only the loading that's asynchronous, everything else is synchronous unless you use `Worker` class of FP11.4 onward.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is for the data to load synchronously so that you can just make the loading call and have it return right away, like so:

```
# (this actually is not actionscript)
fileDataContents = open("file.txt", "r");
```

then have the fileDataContents immediately available to use.

*By design this is not how flash works.*

Loading external data in flash is not multithreaded, but rather **asynchronous**. One very good reason why synchronous loading is not done is that it causes blocking/locking of the program during the operation potentially resulting in a poor user experience.

Take for example, if this is loading a file over the web: what if the user's internet connection had just cut out/hiccupped or had been moved/deleted/modified suddenly on the server? Or what if the file is moderately sized but the user was on dial-up?

This is out of your control in most cases and the resulting behaviour may be that it causes flash to "forever" freeze in the user's browser window as it tries to load, possibly taking down the whole browser with it, ultimately ending in a poor user experience. By blocking/locking the program in that loop you would have no way to recover or respond to the user appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Listening for the COMPLETE event like you have now is the correct way to wait and continue the application flow once done. I can't see how this would become awkward - I suggest updating your question to include information about what's making you uncomfortable about the event system so that I can help you from there.

Perhaps you're just not structuring your code in a way that works well with the event system. Here is how you can set up a very clean, straightforward way of loading some data and starting up the application once done.

Here's the document class, which can be used purely as a channel to load your text data which will be forwarded on to a fresh instance of the actual Application class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{

    private var _application:Application;
    private var _loader:URLLoader;


    public function Main()
    {
        var fileUrl:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.txt");

        _loader = new URLLoader(fileUrl);
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _textLoaded);
    }


    private function _textLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        _loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _textLoaded);

        // Load the main Application with the required text data.
        _application = new Application( _loader.data );
    }

}
```

And then your `Application`, which you can consider your central class.:

```
public class Application
{

    public function Application(textData:String)
    {
        // Here we have access to the required text, and we can
        // begin preparing the main Application.
        trace(textData);
    }

}
```